# No matching function for call to

Tags: c++, vector, int

I got this method where I'm getting lines of userdata from a file, then splitting the lines into parts and then putting those parts into different strings. Then at last, I'm creating a new user object and adding the user object into another vector called users.

```
void userdata::importData(string fname)
{
    g_string g;
    filename= fname;
    string line;
    ifstream file(filename.c_str());
    vector<string> parts;
    while ( file.good() )
    {
       getline (file,line);
       g.split(',', line); 
       vector<string>::iterator i; 

       for(i = parts.begin(); i < parts.end(); i++)
       {
             string usernr = parts.at(0);
             string name = parts.at(1);
             string gender = parts.at(2);
             string age = parts.at(3);
             string profession = parts.at(4);
             string email = parts.at(5);

             user user(usernr , name , gender , age , profession , email );
             users.push_back(user);
       }
       parts.clear();
    }

    file.close();
}
```

The problem is that I'm getting this error on every line where I'm setting the string as the parts.at(int)-value:

```
test.cpp: In method `void userdata::importData(class string)':
test.cpp:186: no matching function for call to `vector<basic_string<char
,string_char_traits<char>,__default_alloc_template<false,0> >,__default_alloc_te
mplate<false,0> >::at (int)'
test.cpp:187: no matching function for call to `vector<basic_string<char
,string_char_traits<char>,__default_alloc_template<false,0> >,__default_alloc_te
mplate<false,0> >::at (int)'
test.cpp:188: no matching function for call to `vector<basic_string<char
,string_char_traits<char>,__default_alloc_template<false,0> >,__default_alloc_te
mplate<false,0> >::at (int)'
test.cpp:189: no matching function for call to `vector<basic_string<char
,string_char_traits<char>,__default_alloc_template<false,0> >,__default_alloc_te
mplate<false,0> >::at (int)'
test.cpp:190: no matching function for call to `vector<basic_string<char
,string_char_traits<char>,__default_alloc_template<false,0> >,__default_alloc_te
mplate<false,0> >::at (int)'
test.cpp:191: no matching function for call to `vector<basic_string<char
,string_char_traits<char>,__default_alloc_template<false,0> >,__default_alloc_te
mplate<false,0> >::at (int)'
```

Anyone knows what might be wrong?

Comment: Just an observation: The for loop should never execute as the code is written. `parts` is always empty. Is this the real code?

Comment: Oh, forgot to mention that the parts vector is actually declared outside the method and is used in a split()-method I've made, so parts is not empty =)

Comment: It works all right for me. Can you reduce this to the simplest code that will still produce the error, then post the whole thing? Also, what compiler are you using?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`std::vector::at()` takes a `size_type` argument, which is unsigned. Perhaps this works:

```
         string usernr = parts.at(0u);
         string name = parts.at(1u);
         string gender = parts.at(2u);
         string age = parts.at(3u);
         string profession = parts.at(4u);
         string email = parts.at(5u);
```

Comment: Tried it, but then I got this error message:

no matching function for call to `vector<basic_string<char
,string_char_traits<char>,__default_alloc_template<false,0> >,__default_alloc_te
mplate<false,0> >::at (unsigned int)'

Comment: @user709712: Try reinstalling your compiler, because your code is fine.

Comment: @unapersson: Well, the code is not "fine", but the error messages he gets are clearly broken.

Comment: @night Comparing an uninitialized iterator to another valid iterator is undefined behaviour.

Comment: @unapersson: I don't see an uninitialized iterator, and even if that would be the case `parts.at(5);` should still compile without an error, which clearly is not the case.

Comment: @unapersson: The iterator is initialized in the for-loop.

Comment: @night You are right - I guess I am unused to seeing C++ code written as if it was C. However, parts never gets set up, so the code is still wrong.

Comment: @unapersson: These errors are happening at compile/link time.  If the function should be working (you could try it vs another compiler or on codepad.org), then the compiler implementation/compiler installation is to blame.  Since they are what he asked about, they are the first thing to address in an answer.  Help with the rest of the code may be great to provide, and might be important, but it isn't top priority.  So, this answer is basically on the right track.

Comment: I forgot to mention that the parts vector is actually declared outside the method and is used in a split()-method I've made, so parts is not empty =)

I also starting to think that the problem is my compiler, because if I compile and run it in Dev-C++, it works perfectly.

Comment: @user In the code you posted, parts is NOT declared outside the method. If you are not posting the real code, there isn't really any way to help you. And DevC++ is a pile of cr*p - much more likely to hide errors than expose them.

Comment: @unapersson: While I'm not a great fan of Dev-C++, it uses MingW gcc as backend, so it can't be that bad.

Comment: @Merlyn Blaming the compiler is the #1 newbie mistake.

Comment: @unapersson: You are becoming annoying now. Please stay ontopic. The user posted a piece of code. This piece of code contained some programming mistakes, but that wasn't the problem. The compiler generated errors about obviously correct code and thereby the compiler is to blame. If you disagree, please react __with content__, instead of your uninformative flaming tone I've seen so far.

Comment: @night Not as annoying as someone who immediately rushes to blame the compiler, and then says "oh, it is not that bad", without even finding out what version of the compiler the OP is using. The OP's code is either wrong, or not the code he is compiling. And how someone who is repeatedly factually wrong (as I have pointed out several times) in your posts here can criticise me, I don't know.

Comment: Sorry unapersson, should've posted in the original post that the code I posted was not the original code, my fault. But I've solved the problem now, installed another compiler and then it worked =)

Answer (score 0):

```
 while ( file.good() )
    {
       getline (file,line);
```

should be:

```
 while ( getline (file,line) )
```

Can you please tell me which book you read told you to test the stream with the good() function? I genuinely want to know this.

Edit: It looks to me as if you never populate the parts vector. And what sort of thing is a g_string? (apart from the, ahem, adult meaning).

Comment: Okey, but that doesn't fix my problem =)

Comment: @user709712: cplusplus.com is great when you need some function info quickly, but the examples and tutorials are horrible. I would suggest buying a C++ book if you really want to learn C++.